# Rails 3.1 + Devise 1.4.9: Why Doesn't ActiveRecord Catch A Failed Save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

*UPDATED* I'm using Devise 1.4.9 for authentication and my Devise-generated User model doesn't seem to be catching the exceptions being thrown by the DB when I try to create a new user with an email address that already exists in the DB. After following cicloon's suggestion (see response below), my code to create a new user is...

```
class Api::RegistrationsController < Api::BaseController

  respond_to :json

  def create
    user = User.new(params[:user])
    user.ensure_authentication_token! 

    if user.valid?
        user.save
        render :json=> user.as_json(:auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email, :user_id=>user.id), :status=>201
        return
    else
        warden.custom_failure!
        render :json=> user.errors, :status=>422
    end
  end
end
```

The Devise-generated migration includes an index for the email attribute, including uniqueness validation...

```
add_index :users, :email, :unique => true
```

And here's the user model...

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :token_authenticatable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :authentication_token 

  validates_uniqueness_of :email

  def ensure_authentication_token!   
    reset_authentication_token! if authentication_token.blank?   
  end  

  def as_json(options={})
    super(:only => [:email, :authentication_token, :id])
  end

end
```

...I would like the database to raise an error during save if the specified email address already existed in the DB, have Rails catch it and execute the else block of code to return a 422 and description of the problem.  It doesn't, instead I get an SQLException error and a crash...

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "users" ("authentication_token", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)):
  app/models/user.rb:33:in `ensure_authentication_token!'
  app/controllers/api/registrations_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

How can I get my code to return a 422 with a description of the error?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Comment: Can you provide some logs? I think your indexes may hadn't been created, so the save is not really failing.

Comment: Any logs in particular? The server logs don't really show much besides the SQLite3 error that I posted above.  Is there any way I can view which indicies have been created for my model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read your post again, now I see what's happening there. You have a database index, and Rails is not aware of that, so when you make @user.save the database throws an exception which is not captured Rails side.

That said, you have two choices:

1.) Capture the exception in Rails:

```
begin
  user.save
  render :json=> user.as_json(:auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email, :user_id=>user.id), :status=>201

rescue
  warden.custom_failure!
  render :json=> user.errors, :status=>422
end
```

2.) Add the validation to your model and check for user.valid?:

On your user model:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

On your controller:

```
  if user.valid?
      user.save
      render :json=> user.as_json(:auth_token=>user.authentication_token, :email=>user.email, :user_id=>user.id), :status=>201
      return
  else
      warden.custom_failure!
      render :json=> user.errors, :status=>422
  end
```

Comment: Thanks, cicloon, I tried both suggestions and neither worked.  Please see my updated question to see my current code.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Nevermind, I found the problem.  I had to move the call to ensure_authentication_token under the if user.valid? line, that fixed it

Comment: user.save doesn't raise exceptions. user.save! will raise both validation exceptions and database exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add the validation to your users model.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

Answer (score 0):

I would wrap this in exception handlers. Try something like this:

```
class Api::RegistrationsController < Api::BaseController

  respond_to :json

  def create
    user = User.new(params[:user])

    status = nil
    json   = nil

    begin
      user.ensure_authentication_token!
      user.save!
      status = 201
      json   = {
        :auth_token => user.authentication_token,
        :email      => user.email,
        :user_id    => user.id
      }
    rescue StandardError => e
      case e
      when ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid, ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique
        # ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid -> Raised by SQLite Adapter
        # ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique  -> Raised by Postgres Adapter
        user.errors[:email] = 'already taken'
      end

      warden.custom_failure!

      status = 422
      json   = user.errors
    end

    render :json => json, :status => status
  end
end
```

Comment: It makes me a little sad to see the postgres and sqlite drivers report exceptions differently. Also note, I haven't tested this w/ MySQL, it might do something else entirely too.

Comment: I would also note, this isn't really a devise specific issue. At the end of the day, your db index is the only thing that can reliably enforce uniqueness. The validator mentioned by Sebi will work nicely in most cases, but not all. Ultimately, you'll have to handle db exceptions to catch all scenarios.